# Microsoft's application installer launches my ClickOnce application

Tags: windows, clickonce

This is the weirdest thing I've ever seen. I wrote [this application](http://www.heliumscraper.com), which is deployed through ClickOnce. After installing my application, I tried to install [this other tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=658), and instead of installing anything, my application launched. Then I uninstalled my application, cleared ClickOnce's cache by running `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache` in CMD, and tried to install Microsoft's tool again, and my application's ClickOnce installer showed up.

Any idea what in the world could cause this?

Comment: ClickOnce and MSI do not share the same product code. Does the problem always happen after the customer clicks a downloaded setup program? Could be the problem of the browser launching the wrong download, who knows. I reproduced this once on Windows 8, but now cannot reproduce anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the same GUID for the installer what microsoft used for their tool. Please generate another GUID for your app and try again.

Also try your installer from a different PC or Virtual Machine. It could be your computer's issue as well.

Comment: Do you know of a way to see an application's GUID? This error was reported by a customer and he states it happened with other applications as well, so I doubt they're all using the same GUID.

Comment: maybe this will help to find your app by GUID http://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/uninstall-application-using-guid-registry or this script  http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/17009-finding-guid-for-specific-application-in-registry/

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that they use the same GUID. Can you regenerate any keys of your application and try again?

Really strange.

Comment: Do you know of a way to see an application's GUID? This error was reported by a customer and he states it happened with other applications as well, so I doubt they're all using the same GUID.